# Why can an Object be cast as an Integer using generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting, floating-point, integer

I found a way to add Floats to an Integer array through generic types. I'm curious why Java doesn't catch this in a runtime error? I tried looking through the docs for any info about this, but I haven't had any luck.

For example, say I have two ArrayLists, one containing Integers, and one containing Floats, like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Float> listFlt = new ArrayList<>();
  
listInt.add(6);
listInt.add(71);
  
listFlt.add(4.92f);
listFlt.add(20.5f);
```

Using generics, I can copy the Floats from listFlt into listInt through a method like this:

```
public static <T extends Number, S extends Number> void copy(ArrayList<T> src, ArrayList<S> dest) {
   for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
       Object x = src.get(i);
       dest.set(i, (S)x);
   }
}
```

Calling it with:

```
ClassName.<Float, Integer>copy(listFlt, listInt);
```

Now, when I print listInt, it displays:

```
4.92
20.5
```

How is it possible to cast an Object as an Integer when generics are involved? And how can listInt store Floats? Thanks!

Comment: Integer is a subclass of Number and Number can hold ints, floats, doubles, longs...

Comment: This is run time type erasure.  The JVM doesn't care what type of objects you put in your `ArrayList`.  All the type checking induced by the type parameters is done at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Using generics, I can copy the Floats from listFlt into listInt through a method like this

Note that inside this method, you are casting to the type parameter `S`:

```
dest.set(i, (S)x);
```

This will cause an unchecked cast warning when you compile it (which you should not ignore!).

It's allowed, but because of type erasure, the JVM will not be able to check at runtime if the cast is allowed.

This is an example of [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution): because of the rules of the Java language and type erasure, you get into a situation where you can add objects into an `ArrayList` that are of the wrong type (in this case: you are adding `Float` objects to a list that is supposed to contain `Integer` objects).

When you just print the list, there is no problem, because in that case Java only needs to call `toString()` on the elements of the list, and that method exists for all objects.

But when you try to get an `Integer` out of the list, you will get a `ClassCastException`:

```
ClassName.<Float, Integer>copy(listFlt, listInt);

Integer i = listInt.get(0); // ClassCastException: Float cannot be cast to Integer
```

It's an unfortunate consequence of a combination of the rules of Java, which are partly the way they are because of backward compatibility, and the way that Java works with generics (with type erasure).

**Point to remember**: Do not ignore "unchecked cast" warnings; they are a hint that there is possible heap pollution going on in your code.

Comment: I think you've sort of buried the lede in this otherwise excellent answer: __Generics are a figment of `javac`'s imagination__: The runtime has no idea what they are, and therefore can't check any of it.